# Стоит ли создавать пустые классы для поиска объекта? Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Создавая  игры на unity у меня часто бывает ситуация, когда надо взять объект по типу, однако наименование классов не способствуют легкости чтения кода в дальнейшем.
Пример:

```
GameObject player = GetParentComponent<MoveController>();
```

Не лучше ли будет создать пустой класс Player на нашем игроке и уже брать объект так?

```
GameObject player = GetParentComponent<Player>();
```

Comment: Какая-то ерунда написана если честно. Классы могут быть названы тоже не одним словом......к тому же, класс/компонент должен быть назван так, чем он является на самом деле.......искать надо то, что ищешь на самом деле, переменные надо называть так, чем они являются на самом деле....... Если тебе нужен компонент "пирожок", а ты делаешь класс "Сковорода" - то это невереный подход....... вот если бы этот пирожок был бы тесно связан с предметом, например "Пекарь" который испечёт - тогда ок......... а то, что выше - фигня какая-то)

Comment: А ещё можно делать классы А,B,C, и т.д. - тогда места сколько освободится))

Comment: `MoveController playerController = GetParentComponent<MoveController>();` - не? Переименовать `MoveController` попонятнее?